# isTransparentResolver() in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I have below code need to change it to wicket 6.6, but isTransparentResolver() is removed and I am trying according to this link

- https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@wicket.apache.org/msg17546.html
  but no use, anybody have solution for below code?

  ```
  add(new WebMarkupContainer("bodyElement") {
      @Override
      public boolean isTransparentResolver() {
          return true;
      }


      @Override
      protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
          super.onComponentTag(tag);
          if ((usrLoginHstryList == null || usrLoginHstryList.isEmpty()) &&
                  (usrChangeHstryList == null || usrChangeHstryList.isEmpty())) {
              tag.put("onload", "hideHistoryButtons();");
          } else if (usrLoginHstryList == null || usrLoginHstryList.isEmpty()) {
              tag.put("onload", "hideUserLoginHstryBtn();");
          } else if (usrChangeHstryList == null || usrChangeHstryList.isEmpty()) {
              tag.put("onload", "hideUserChngHstryBtn();");
          }
      }
  });
  ```

Comment: Have you  tried  with `TransparentWebMarkupContainer`?

Comment: I tried , but am not sure how to use that component with respect to above code, Below code i have written but am not sure it is correct or not.


add (new TransparentWebMarkupContainer("bodyElement"){
   
   @Override
   protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
    super.onComponentTag(tag);
    tag.put("onload", "initDisplay();");
   }
  }
    
 );

Comment: Yeah it seems correct to me . No issue

Comment: Thanks, I have written it using TransparentWebMarkupContainer and isTransparentResolver() not added in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have written this using TransparentWebMarkupContainer

```
add(new TransparentWebMarkupContainer("bodyElement"){
            @Override
            protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
                super.onComponentTag(tag);
                if((usrLoginHstryList == null || usrLoginHstryList.isEmpty()) && (usrChangeHstryList == null || usrChangeHstryList.isEmpty())){
                    tag.put("onload", "hideHistoryButtons();");
                }else if(usrLoginHstryList == null || usrLoginHstryList.isEmpty()){
                        tag.put("onload", "hideUserLoginHstryBtn();");
                }else if(usrChangeHstryList == null ||usrChangeHstryList.isEmpty()){
                        tag.put("onload", "hideUserChngHstryBtn();");
                }
            }   

        });
```